# Unable to access jarfile error

Tags: java, batch-file, jar

I am launching my application through a batch file on windows(10) startup. This is what i have in my batch file -

```
start javaw -jar javaApplication.jar`
```

When windows starts i get the

> Unable to access jarfile javaApplcation.jar

However, the problem is that after this error message the application is still being launched and works perfectly. What is the reason that the jar is being accessed but I'm still getting the unable to access the jar error, and how to avoid it? Couldn't find any answers to this specific case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you have start in front.
Just try

```
javaw -jar ...
```

or

```
java -jar ...
```

Comment: If i don't use start, then 1) my command prompt appears and doesn't disappear 2) i still get the unable to access jarfile error

Comment: I'm sorry , the java -jar actually works. I thought that javaw is being used to avoid the visibility of command prompt at the start of windows. However, sadly i still get the command prompt for 1-2 seconds when using java -jar. Does it mean that by using java jar- it is impossible to hide the appearance of the command prompt?